# Grouping a RallyStore by a field on a RallyGrid

Tags: rally

I have created a Rally.data.WsapiDataStore with the model PortfolioItem/Feature.

Now I call the following to turn on grouping in the store:

```
 piStore.group('ValueScore');
```

But when try to display this grouped store in a rallygrid, it freezes up the browser: it displays one grid fine, but then it seems to loop through and display another below it, and so on and so on.

I have added the following to the grid spec so that it groups:

```
        features: [{
            ftype: 'grouping',
            groupHeaderTpl: '{name}',
            startCollapsed: true,
        }]
```

If I don't call piStore.group, it displays fine, but of course, no grouping so I presume the store is ok.

If I construct my own store on the fly (and fill it with data from the piStore), it works fine, so I presume grouping on RallyGrids is ok. But this solution is not good because I loose many advantages of using the Rally Store like being able to write items back if they are modified

Is this my bug, a Rally bug, or a Sencha bug?  Any good way around it?

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "it displays one grid fine, but then it seems to loop through and display another below it..." ? Does it display one of the groupings Ok and then choke on the rest? Or do you have multiple grids?

Comment: It creates multiple grids-- it renders the first grid as you would expect, but then it keeps going and adding on the same grid again to the bottom of the window.